# How can I achieve a three column layout in a Windows Form?

Tags: .net, winforms, tablelayoutpanel

I am striving for a three column layout in a Windows Form, with a fixed size central column, and two autosizing side columns, so when the form resizes, the centre column is always in the centre, and the two side columns always take up half each of the remaining space.

I have tried this with a TableLayoutPanel, but as soon as I set the middle column to fixed and the outer two to autosize, one of the side columns vanishes from the designer.

Comment: Have you tried setting the side columns to 50%?

Comment: @Koen I just tried now, it works. You should answer with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the two side columns to 50% and the middle column to a fixed size should do the trick.

Comment: I accepted this answer because Koen actually solved my problem with his comment, which was posted just before Daniel's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Autosize will automatically adjust based on space required by control within the column.  If the column is empty, then it will disappear from the designer as it is 0px

I think you need to use %

Example:

Column0 - 50%
Column1 - 400px
Column2 - 50%

Might work?

Answer (score 0):

It work perfect with TableLayoutPanel. Set the TableLayoutPanel Dock to DockStyle.Fill

Coloum0 30%
Coloum1 40%
Coloum2 30%

Comment: I specifically want the middle column a fixed size, i.e. not a percentage.